# Как мне сделать на php написать так

Tags: php

У меня есть два переменных a и б из select * from.

а - дате

б - это какойта значения

01.07.2020 - 1

02.07.2020 - 1

05.07.2020 - 2

06.07.2020 - 2

07.07.2020 - 2

10.07.2020 - 1

11.07.2020 - 1

14.07.2020 - 3

17.07.2020 - 1

18.07.2020 - 1

19.07.2020 - 1

23.07.2020 - 1

24.07.2020 - 1

Как мне сделать на php,что написать так

01.07.2020 - старт

02.07.2020 - энд

05.07.2020 - старт

07.07.2020 - энд

10.07.2020 - старт

11.07.2020 - энд

14.07.2020 - старт

14.07.2020 - энд

17.07.2020 - старт

24.07.2020 - энд

Comment: Приведите пример того, что вы пытались сделать сами и какой результат вы получили.

Comment: Не надо делать это на PHP - перепишите запрос и сразу замените числа на соответствующие строковые литералы.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr=array("01.07.2020 - 1",

"02.07.2020 - 1",

"05.07.2020 - 2",

"06.07.2020 - 2",

"07.07.2020 - 2",

"10.07.2020 - 1",

"11.07.2020 - 1",

"14.07.2020 - 3",

"17.07.2020 - 1",

"18.07.2020 - 1",

"19.07.2020 - 1",

"23.07.2020 - 1",

"24.07.2020 - 1");


foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  if(($key % 2) == 0){
$sel="start";
    $row=explode(" - ", $value);


    $new[]=$row[0]." - ".$sel;
}else{
  $sel="end";
    $row=explode(" - ", $value);


    $new[]=$row[0]." - ".$sel;
}
}
print_r($new);
?>
```

Comment: Зачем вы дублируете explode и конкатинацию с добавлением в $new? Они же не отличаются для чётной и нечётной итерации. Ну и скорее всего автор мечтает о другом. Типа: 1,2,2,1 = 1-start, 2-start, 2-stop, 1-stop.